# Regression fit Issue: could not convert string to float: '-'

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to come up with a solution to convert the datatypes of column in pandas dataframe. I have the following columns in my data: User Id, age, gender, marital status and prod code. I want to convert the following columns to float. I used to .replace function to change the values inside the entry

```
ITEM_ID prod_code   id  gender  age marital_status
0   1   0   156873.0    -   -   -
1   2   1   156872.0    0   29  -
2   3   2   156871.0    0   24  -
3   4   3   156870.0    0   25  -
4   5   4   156869.0    0   23  -
```

Got the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the data type of a column all you have to do is to use the code below:

```
df['name of the column'] = df['name of the column'].astype('float64')
```

However, the problem you are facing now is something else
There are values in the columns that are strings such as '-' which you have to replace with missing values and later fill them.
in order to do this, you can use the code below:

```
df['name of the column'] = df['name of the column'].replace('-',np.nan)
```

To avoid this sort of issue you can use df.describe() or df.info() to see the type of each column. In this case, if a column is all numbers but it says it is an object means there are values that you have to check such as this one.